# Do Maclane and Moerdijk mean "Coherent logic" when they write "Geometric logic"?

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

Just want to make sure. The nlab says [coherent logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+logic) differs from [geometric logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+theory) in that it only allows finite disjunctions. At the beginning of chapter X, Maclane and Moerdijk seem to define geometric formulas as the nlab defines coherent formulas.

So, by nlab conventions, should I replace 'geometric formula' by 'coherent formula' throughout the book?

Comment: Yes, you should. The Elephant uses the same convention as the nLab, by the way.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt thanks! I'll delete my question in a minute or so.

Comment: Why would you delete it? That's not how MSE works. Someone else may have the same question one day.

Comment: @KevinCarlson no problem, won't delete.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Arrow Did so. I hesitated because the comment doesn't provide any background information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should. The Elephant uses the same convention as the nLab, by the way.